# A gamified productivity app for Android

Tags: android, productivity

I'd like an app like [productiveapp.io](http://www.productiveapp.io), but for Android.

Essentially:

- Set up regular productivity/lifestyle goals.
- Earn streaks and badges.
- Give push notifications to remind you to do the daily thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think [LifeRPG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jayvant.liferpgmissions&hl=en) is what you're looking for. It has all the features that you've requested and more.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll check it out. Unfortunately - it looks like they could do with a LOT of design.

Answer (score 1):

Following Kidus's suggestion, I'm going to suggest [Habitica](https://habitica.com/). It's a similar RPG-eque habit app.

- Is on iOS, Android and Browser
- Is an open source project, with a what looks like quite an active community - so you can contribute superficial assets like quests, sprites etc - or contribute features etc.
- It looks like integration with IFTTT is a requested feature - so that might come in the future.
- The UX generally looks a lot better than the other apps I've looked at.